# Parse : [PFInstallation currentInstallation] returns null

Tags: notifications, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios7.1

I have been revolving around this issue for a very long time but i couldn't get any relevant solution for this.I am intended to send push notification to device within certain miles (Miles would be decided by the user).
I use the following code on click of a button, which was working fine earlier but now i came across this pathetic problem.

```
if (setMiles == 0) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Broadcast Alert" message:@"Please select broadcast range" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else {


        PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        NSLog(@"%@",installation);
        [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                PFQuery *userQuery = [PFInstallation query];
                [userQuery whereKey:@"location"
                       nearGeoPoint:geoPoint
                        withinMiles:setMiles];
                NSString *str_CurrentDeviceToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[installation objectForKey:@"deviceToken"]];
                [userQuery whereKey:@"deviceToken" notEqualTo:str_CurrentDeviceToken];
                NSLog(@"%@",userQuery);


                NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      notifTextView.text, @"alert",
                                      @"1", @"badge", 
                                      @"", @"sound",
                                      nil]; 


                PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init]; 
                [push setQuery:userQuery]; 
                [push setData:data]; 
                [push sendPushInBackground]; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                NSLog(@"%@", error); 
                return; 
            } 
        }];


       [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

        }
```

and in my appDelegate file i do :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{

    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"User is currently at %f, %f", geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude);

            PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
            [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
            currentInstallation[@"location"] = geoPoint;
            [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
        } else { 
            NSLog(@"%@", error); 
            return; 
        } 
    }];


}



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    NSLog(@"userInfo= %@",userInfo);
}
```

This is when i log the installation object :

```
<PFInstallation:toE395mvKe:(null)> {
    appIdentifier = "myAddID";
    appName = myAppName;
    appVersion = "1.0";
    badge = 0;
    deviceToken = MyDeviceToken;
    deviceType = ios;
    installationId = "MyInstallationID";
    location = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x17d660>";
    parseVersion = "1.2.19";
    timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
    "user_type" = Main;
}
```

**PS : I am no longer able to receive the push notification's.**

I am not sure why this is happening as it used to work just fine earlier.Any help is appreciated deeply.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but the free features of Parse only allow you to upload one version of your push notification certificate. If you've uploaded a debug version of your certificate and are running a release version, you won't get any push notifications. Also, does Parse show that it's sending any push notifications? (you can check online)

Comment: You can try and send push notifications using a simpler set up, ie. send a push notification without a restriction on location, see if that works etc.

Comment: @shim : I have tried sending the push notification through web console of Parse and i am able to successfully receive the notification.Also if i use simple setup as you've mentioned, still i am not able to receive the notification.
If you could please elaborate about the certificate stuff...Thank you

Comment: The push certificates are generated on the Apple developer portal. Only one can be uploaded to Parse. Read more here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1